# mysqldump: Got error: 1017: Can't find file: './access.frm' (errno: 13) when using LOCK TABLES

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-backups, database-restore

Getting this error when I try to create a mysqldump of a database I have restored.

The full error is
`mysqldump: Got error: 1017: Can't find file: './b67_db/access.frm' (errno: 13) when using LOCK TABLES` where `b67_db` is the name of the database.

I have navigated into the `var/lib/mysql/b67_db/` directory and `access.frm` is present.

Comment: This is probably a better fit for dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

U can try below command. This worked for me:

`# mysqldump --skip-lock-tables -u<db_user> -p<db_user_password> database_name > /root/database_dump.sql`

Reference : https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213931725-mysqldump-table-doesn-t-exist-when-using-LOCK-TABLES